# Tapping pushpin on Bingmap displays another pushpin WP7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, bing-maps

There are multiple pushpins . If we Tap on a pushpin displays another pushpin with dynamic data template which contains image and two textblock control in windows phone c#. Kindly please help.

```
<my:Map HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="ServiceMap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"    MapPan="ServiceMap_MapPan"> 
<my:MapItemsControl x:Name="mapControl" Margin="0,0,0,44" /></my:Map>

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PushpinControlTemplate1" TargetType="my:Pushpin">
<Grid Name="contentGrid" Width="40"  Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
<Image x:Name="Layer_1" Height="75" Source="/Images/CurrentLoc.png"/>
</Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PushPinTemplate2" TargetType="my:Pushpin">
<Grid Name="contentGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Silver" Opacity="0.7">
<Image Name="imgPin" Source="/Images/maponinemarker.png" Height="50" Width="50">      </Image>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Margin="6,0" FontSize="24" Name="txtId"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="50,50,50,50" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

```
    Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();             
    pin.Location = e.Position.Location;
    pin.Template = (ControlTemplate)(this.Resources["PushpinControlTemplate1"]);
    mapControl.Items.Add(pin);
    pin.Tap+=(s,tapEve)=>
    {
    Pushpin contentPin = new Pushpin();
    contentPin.Location = e.Position.Location;
    contentPin.Template = (ControlTemplate)(this.Resources["PushpinControlTemplate2"]);
    MapView.Children.Add(contentPin);
    };
```

the first pushpin displays correctly. when tapping the first pushpin how can it displays the second with the template of PushpinControlTemplate2. if we assign the value to template it doent get assigned

Comment: Can you please explain the issue a little more and provide code samples where possible?

Comment: I have 'n' number of pushpins to load in map control dynamically. If when tapping one pushpin it will show another pushpin which have a stackpanel as content of pushpin. stackpanel have binding controls such as textblock and image.

Comment: If you search, there is a lot of sample code out there to handle this. Please show your workings so far - what you have tried, what doesn't work, etc

Comment: @NeilTurner Edited the question. Please view it